# APK analysis using MobSF (Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) framework, shows code analysis empty

Tags: android, security

I have analysed the APK using MobSF (Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) framework, the static analysis report is generated but the code analysis of java source is showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to issues with the APK or incorrectly configured MobSF instance. Join our slack channel for limited support and debugging: https://mobsf.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtNzM2NTAyNzA1MjgxLTdjMzkzNDc3ZjdiMjkwZTZhMmFhNDlkZmMwZDhjNDNmYTAzYWE5NGZlMDIzYzliNTdiMDQ2MTRlYjU1MjkyNGM